# Excel - Copy format from one chart series to another

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I want to be able to copy all formatting from only one chart series to another.
One way of doing this is via VBA, traversing all format properties in the source series and setting the target series accordingly.

Is there any other alternative? (copy and paste-special-formats would copy all chart format, so I guess it is not useful).

PS: using VBA has a few downsides:

1. It is quite cumbersome to code this.
2. It may not be transferable from one Excel version to another (this applies to many other pieces of code, anyway).
3. Some properties, or combinations thereof, can not be set with VBA.

I have actually coded something, but it is limited since it copies only parts of the format, and it is bound by item 3.

Comment: Point 1 can be handled using recording a macro but you are are spot on regarding Points 2 and Points 3. One way I can think of is to copy the chart and create a copy of it and then reset it's source data

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Regarding task #1: Unfortunately, 1) one would have to traverse all format features, which is very laborious as well (but likely less than writing it in VBA), 2) macro recording does not produce a complete output of the actions taken. Regarding copying the chart, I guess I did not understand what you propose.

Comment: Maybe I might have misunderstood you... Did you mean `all formatting from only one chart series to another` in the same chart?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - That is the main use that I had in mind. But I would like to do this also for copying between series in different charts, for charts that contain other series, data labels, formatting, etc., that I want to keep (i.e., I am not thinking about charts that can be created from scratch). I guess that anything good for series in the same chart would be ok for series in different charts, that is why I did not specify one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Format the first series, select each successively and press F4 for each, per:

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/quickly-format-multiple-data-series-one-chart-t3536724.html

Comment: [This thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/f4-functionality-in-excel-2010-chart-f4-ability/d6e7b7d4-f374-46d7-8e47-051ce5f2b9f3), e.g., shows that F4 does not work, from 2007 onwards.