# Excel - Format many chart series incrementally

Tags: excel, charts

I want to be able to format many chart series with a very similar format, varying only one feature (e.g., marker line color), avoiding doing it by hand.

One way that I conceived for doing this is by: 1) setting the format for the first series in the group, 2) copying the format to the rest, 3) changing only the selected feature, using values in an array, e.g.

Question
[Excel - Copy format from one chart series to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495949/excel-copy-format-from-one-chart-series-to-another)
relates to task #2. As long as I do not have a good means for carrying out task #2, is there an alternative way of achieving the overall objective?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just iterate over all the series you wish to change and call a function that sets the format for the current series. The function can then just accept the one feature you wish to change as a parameter. For example something like this (just some pseudo code so you can imagine the solution easier):

```
foreach series in seriesCollection
   format(series, markerLineColor)
```

And function format looks something like this:

```
format(Series series, ColorFormat markerLineColor)
   // set all the common parameters
   series.Format.Line.Forecolor = markerLineColor
```

Comment: This is what I proposed.